# Converting Webelement.text to a string

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use machine learning to perform sentiment analysis on data from twitter. To aggregate the data, I've made a class which will mine and 
pre-process data. In order to clean and pre-process the data, I'd like to convert each tweet's text to a string. However, when the line of code in the inner for loop in the massMine method is called, i get a WebDriverException: no such session. The relevant bits of code are below, any input is appreciated, thanks.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import numpy as np
import pandas
import re
class TweetMiner(object):


  def __init__(self):
    self.base_url = u'https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3A'
    self.raw_data = []           
  def mineTweets(self, query, tweet_quota):
      '''
       Mine data from a singular twitter account,
       input consists of a twitter handle, and a 
       value indicating how much data to mine
       Ex: “@diddy” should be inputted as “diddy”
    '''
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = self.base_url + query
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    for _ in range(tweet_quota):
      body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
      time.sleep(0.2)
    tweets = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')
    for tweet in tweets:
      print(tweet.text)
    browser.close() 
    return tweets

  def massMine(self, inputArray, dataSize):
    '''
       Mine data from an array of twitter
       accounts, input array consists of twitter
       handles and a value indicating how much
       data to mine
       Ex: “@diddy” should be inputted as “diddy”
    '''
    for user in inputArray:
      rtn = ""
      tweets = self.mineTweets(user,dataSize)
      for tweet in tweets:
        rtn += (tweet.text)
    return rtn
```

EDIT: I don't know what caused this error - but if anyone stumbles across this post with a similar error I was able to workaround by simply writing each tweet to a text file.

Comment: Is your chrome/selenium up to date? From searching SO it seems that this a likely culprit.

Comment: At which line are you seeing the error?

Comment: Yes, my selenium is up to date, and my chrome is also up to date. Webelement.text just doesn't seem to return a string. I'll update this later because i'm busy today, but I'm going to try to workaround by outputting Webelement.text to a file and then parsing it into a string.

Comment: Have you tried `element.GetAttribute("value");`??

Comment: Yes, this throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I use to get this error when I have opened too many browser instances and haven't closed it properly (both via automation script or manually). When other browser instances were killed one by one this error is removed. I found that `C:\Users\(yourAccountName)\AppData\Local\Temp` directory is totally filled up and hence causing the `NoSuchSession` error.

Preferred solution will be to see if too many browsers/tabs are open. Remove them. Or manually remove all the contents inside above `Temp` path and try.